# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read(), but I call Read() first

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to process some data (mostly double values) from MySQL database. 
I am getting this error message:

```
Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()
```

Watch window:

```
readerCompare1["Fe1"]   'readerCompare1["Fe1"]' threw an exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'  object {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}
```

I have used this exact code before and it worked perfectly.

CODE:

```
  for (int k = 1; k <= pocet; k++)
            {
                string queryCompare = " SELECT F1 AS Fe1, F2 AS Fe2, F3 AS Fe3, F4 AS Fe4, F5 AS Fe5, F6 AS Fe6, F7 AS Fe7, F8 AS Fe8, cluster FROM features WHERE ID=" + k;
                MySqlCommand cmdCompare = new MySqlCommand(queryCompare, conect);
                readerCompare1 = cmdCompare.ExecuteReader();
                readerCompare1.Read();
                //  MessageBox.Show("OK");
                double f1 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe1"].ToConvertibleDouble());   //Exception THROWN HERE
                double f2 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe2"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                double f3 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe3"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                double f4 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe4"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                double f5 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe5"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                double f6 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe6"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                double f7 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe7"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                double f8 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe8"].ToConvertibleDouble());
                // string f88 = readerCompare["Fe8"].ToString();
                //double f8 = Convert.ToDouble(f88, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                int cluster = Convert.ToInt32(readerCompare1["cluster"].ToString());

                readerCompare1.Close();
```

The exception is thrown on the line: double f1 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe1"] ...

But as you can see I am calling the Read() first:

```
readerCompare1.Read();
```

Can anyone explain please, why is this happening?
Thank you

Comment: Could it be that your query does not return records? Check what does `readerCompare1.Read()` returns: `true` or `false`.

Comment: Please follow given answer. My question is why don't you use `IN` keyword in the query and execute it once for all ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Read` method returns a boolean telling you whether or not any information is available. If this returns false, you cannot attempt to read from the reader.

You should wrap your code in an if statement (or a while statement, depending on how many results you expect):

```
if(readerCompare1.Read()) {
    double f1 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe1"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f2 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe2"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f3 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe3"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f4 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe4"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f5 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe5"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f6 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe6"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f7 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe7"].ToConvertibleDouble());
    double f8 = Convert.ToDouble(readerCompare1["Fe8"].ToConvertibleDouble());
}
```

[MySqlDataReader examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html)